# Error al concatenar datos en php

Tags: php, mysql

En el siguiente código, es un `insert` a la tabla `inventory_list`, este funciona perfectamente, tengo sus parámetros... como observación, en la tabla tengo el campo `registerDate`, el cual no lo pongo como parámetro ya que sera tomado del sistema.

Bueno lo que necesito hacer es como obtener el `numFile`(id autoincrementable)  que se acaba de registrar, ya que con este formare un `folio` en base a una `palabra`, `numFile` y `año`, el cual debe quedar así: `EST-0013-19`. Este se pondrá en el campo `folio` de la tabla.

Haciendo prueba en `postman` el `insert` de los otros datos lo hace correctamente, haciendo un `echo($update);` del `query` de `update`, genera un `0 (cero)` el cual se ingresa en el campo de `folio` y sale el siguiente error:

> > **Warning**:  A non-numeric value encountered in
> >     **C:\xampp\htdocs\WareHouse\apis\article.php** on line **551**
> >     
> >  
> >  **Warning**:  A non-numeric value encountered in
> >     **C:\xampp\htdocs\WareHouse\apis\article.php** on line **551**
>
> {"status":"0","errorMessage":"ITEM registrado"}

Ejecutando el mismo pedazo de código en el `sql` de `PhpMyAdmin`, si hace al actualización, y el campo se llena con los respectivo datos, que mencione arriba.

```
  UPDATE inventory_list SET folio = 
( SELECT x.max FROM ( SELECT CONCAT('EST-00',MAX(numFile),"-",YEAR(CURDATE()))max FROM inventory_list ) x );
```

Entonces creo mi problema es como lo estoy aplicando en el codigo `PHP`, tal vez no estoy mandando bien el dato al campo o me falta algo mas pero no se que es... Alguien pudiera ayudarme?

Codigo `PHP`:

```
else if(isset($_POST['description_item']) && isset($_POST['price_item'])
    && isset($_POST['manufacturer']) && isset($_POST['model_item']) && isset($_POST['reorder_Level'])
    && isset($_POST['target_Stock']) && isset($_POST['imageName']) && isset($_POST['commentt'])
    && isset($_POST['fkEngineer']) && isset($_POST['fkCategory']) && isset($_POST['fkLocation'])
    && isset($_POST['fkSupplier']) && isset($_POST['fkUnit'])&& isset($_POST['fkSubCat']))
  {

      $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();

      //$pdo->lastInsertId();
      date_default_timezone_set('America/Tijuana');
      $hoy = date("Y-m-d");
      $year = date("y");

      $query = 'INSERT INTO inventory_list (folio,description_item,price_item,manufacturer,model_item,
      reorder_Level,target_Stock,image,registerDate,commentt,fkEngineer,fkCategory,fkLocation,fkSupplier,fkUnit,fkSubCat)
      VALUES (?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);';

      $update="UPDATE inventory_list SET folio = ( SELECT x.max FROM ( SELECT CONCAT('EST-00',MAX(numFile),"-",YEAR(CURDATE()))max FROM inventory_list ) x )";

      $result = $connection->executeNonQuery($query,array($update,$_POST['description_item'], $_POST['price_item'] ,
      $_POST['manufacturer'], $_POST['model_item'], $_POST['reorder_Level'], $_POST['target_Stock'], $_POST['imageName'],
      $hoy, $_POST['commentt'] ,$_POST['fkEngineer'],$_POST['fkCategory'],$_POST['fkLocation'],$_POST['fkSupplier'],$_POST['fkUnit'],$_POST['fkSubCat']));

      if ($result > 0)
      {
// $update="UPDATE inventory_list SET folio = ( SELECT x.max FROM ( SELECT CONCAT('EST-00',MAX(numFile),"-",YEAR(CURDATE()))max FROM inventory_list ) x )";

        echo json_encode(array(
          'status' => '0',
          'errorMessage' => 'ITEM registrado'
        ));
        }
      else
      {
        echo json_encode(array(
          'status' => '2',
          'errorMessage' => 'ITEM no registrado'
        ));
      }
}
```

**Nota:
Como el caso de la fecha, el parámetro `folio`, no lo puse ya que creo que sera creado automáticamente, si lo pusiera tendría que ponerlo yo, y eso no es lo que necesito.**

He pensado en hacer, que después de insertar obtenga el `numFile` y haga todo lo anterior mencionado,y poner el código después de `if ($result > 0)` pero me falta una linea para que ingrese a la columna `folio`

Comment: Intenta reacomodando las comillas simple y las comillas dobles, prueba de esta forma a ver como te va: `$addFolio = "UPDATE inventory_list SET folio = 'EST"."-"."00".$saveDate."-".$year."'";`

Comment: $saveDate es el resultado de una query, tienes que coger el valor dentro del resultado para el update no esa variable

Comment: Como dice @Carmen: "$saveDate es el resultado de una query" por lo que debes de obtener el valor del id dentro del resultado. tbn los nombres de las variables no tienen ningun nombre significativo con lo que haces, es como si ubieras copiado y pegado el codigo y empezaste a editarlo. Creo que debes de reorganizar el codigo por que el select y el insert como que no tienen mucho sentidos (no veo donde usas el **WHERE**) al menos que tengas pensado afectar a todos los registro de la tabla.

Comment: Cómo se ha dicho, no estás recuperando el dato que te trae el `SELECT`, aunque puedes optimizar tu código escribiendo solamente la consulta `UPDATE`, poniendo el `SELECT` como una sub-consulta.

Comment: La actualización que quieres se puede lograr mediante una sola consulta. Por ejemplo si estás usando MySQL, sería: `UPDATE inventory_list 
    SET folio = 
        (
            SELECT 
                x.max 
            FROM (
                    SELECT CONCAT('EST-00',MAX(numFile),"-",YEAR(CURDATE())) max FROM inventory_list
                 ) x
        );` Aquí, mediante `YEAR(CURDATE())` obtendrías el año de la fecha actual. Con `CONCAT` concatenas los otros valores. La sub-consulta obtendría el valor deseado y se haría la actualización. En otros manejadores sería casi igual.

Comment: @VirusDetected lo mejor ubiera sido que te crearas una nueva pregunta, por que la edicion que realizaste difiere literalmente de la original, puede que este bajo el mismo contexto, pero aun asi ha cambiado bastante. Esto lo unico que provoca es que las respuesta que ya te dejaron anteriormente difieran de la nueva edicion que realizaste, lo que conlleva que cualquiera puede entrar y votar negativo a esas respuesta, porque a simple vista difiere de lo que preguntas.

Comment: Perfecto lo cambiare, gracias.

Comment: No estoy diciendo que no hay que editar, solo que si se lleva un lapso de tiempo desde la ultima edicion y adicional lo que modificas cambia bastante entonces para **mí** es mejor crear una nueva pregunta en la cual puede hacer un parentesis de la anterior en la nueva redaccion, para que no vayan a reportala como duplicado. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

este código:

```
$queryDate = "SELECT  max(numFile) as max from inventory_list";
$saveDate = $connection->executeQuery($queryDate,array($_POST['numFile']));
```

Te devuelve un array asi:

|max|

|1|

si deseas obtener el número debes llamar el campo max en $saveDate, así:

```
$addFolio = "UPDATE inventory_list SET folio = 'EST-00'".$saveDate['max']."-".$year;
```

*Nota*
El último id insertado lo puedes obtener sin tener que hacer un select así:

```
$ultimoId = mysqli_insert_id($connetion);
```

y en el query pones

```
$addFolio = "UPDATE inventory_list SET folio = 'EST-00'".$ultimoId."-".$year;
```

Saludos, espero te sirva.