# Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

Soy nuevo en programación y estoy tratando de armar un pequeño programa con xampp y sublime text, en php.

Tengo una primera parte en donde hago un registro de proveedores en una tabla con su respectivo ID y otros datos.

Luego hago otro registro paralelo en otra tabla, de las marcas que podrían llegar a ofrecer estos mismos proveedores, en donde pongo el nombre de la marca, el nombre del proveedor correspondiente a esa marca y otra columna donde quisiera que vaya el número de ID del proveedor que se genera automáticamente en la otra tabla de proveedores con el PRIMARY KEY (además agrego un created_at).

El problema que me surge en el código es el siguiente:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\estudiomanager.com\test\marcas\php\registrom2.php on line 17

Este es el código PHP que estoy usando:

```
<?php 
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$db="focus";
$con = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db);

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$proveedor = $_POST['proveedor'];
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];


$selectid = "SELECT id FROM proveedores WHERE nombre = '$proveedor'";
$result = $con->query($selectid);

$sql = "INSERT INTO marcas (nombre,proveedor,descripcion,id_proveedor,created_at) VALUES ($nombre,$proveedor,$descripcion,$result,NOW)";

?>
```

La línea 17 es la linea del $sql = "INSERT INTO... etc.
Es decir, cuando trato de insertar los datos del formulario, y luego la consulta que hace del ID de la tabla proveedor correspondiente para insertarlo en la tabla de las marcas, no se cómo debería convertir el dato o los datos a un string.

Muchas gracias por leer, saludos a todos.

Comment: en que parte del código estas usando `mysqli_result`?

Comment: Sinceramente, desconozco, no tengo en ningún lado una sentencia mysqli_result.
Sin embargo... probé el script sin la variable $result del id_proveedor en el INSERT TO del @sql y funcionó.. el tema es que sigo sin poder añadir el ID que necesito de la otra tabla.

Answer (score 1):

cuando ejecutas:

```
$selectid = "SELECT id FROM proveedores WHERE nombre = '$proveedor'";
$result = $con->query($selectid);
```

En $result se guarda un array de tipo:

```
|id|   
|1|
```

Así que en el INSERT debes obtener el numero así:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO marcas (nombre, proveedor, descripcion, id_proveedor, created_at) VALUES ($nombre, $proveedor, $descripcion, $result['id'], NOW)";
```

Te recomiendo que mires la solución de este [POST](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/230834/error-al-concatenar-datos-en-php/230849#230849)

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

No pude solucionar el tema del:

> Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Lo que hice directamente fue cambiar el script para poder realizar la acción que necesitaba.

El script que uso ahora es el siguiente:

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if(isset($_POST["nombre"]) && isset($_POST["proveedor"]) && isset($_POST["descripcion"])) {
        if($_POST["nombre"]!="" && $_POST["proveedor"]!=""){
            include "conexion.php";

            $found = false;
            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM marcas WHERE nombre=\"$_POST[nombre]\"";
            $query = $con->query($sql1);
            while ($r=$query->fetch_array()) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
            if($found){
                print "<script>alert(\"La marca ya está registrada.\");window.location='../index.php';</script>";
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO marcas (nombre,proveedor,descripcion,id_proveedor,created_at) VALUE (\"$_POST[nombre]\",\"$_POST[proveedor]\",\"$_POST[descripcion]\",(SELECT id FROM proveedores WHERE nombre = \"$_POST[proveedor]\"),NOW())";
            $query = $con->query($sql);
            if($query!=null){
                print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../index.php';</script>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```