# Como guardar resultado de consulta en php

Tags: php, sql, select

Como le puedo hacer para guardar el resultado del select donde estoy obteniendo el ultimo `numFile` registrado y actualizar el campo `folio` para que quede **EST-0040-19**.

Al hacer la prueba si actualiza el campo, pero queda asi `EST-0000-19`no estoy obteniendo el `numFile`

```
$select="SELECT numFile FROM inventory_list ORDER BY numFile desc LIMIT 1";
        //como guardo el resultado
             $insert = "UPDATE inventory_list set folio = ? WHERE numFile = (SELECT max(numFile) from (select * from inventory_list) as newTable)";
             //como guardo el resultado

             //como concateno para la actualizacion
             $resultUp = $connection->executeNonQuery($insert,array('EST-00'.aqui va el ultimo numFile.'-'.$year));
             echo ($resultUp.'resulUp');
```

No estoy segura si es la manera de guardar el resultado de la consulta, para luego utilizarla en la actualización..

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($result);`?

Comment: `0resultstring(1) "0"`

Comment: El `SELECT` **no** está funcionando entonces. Debes revisar qué pasa con ese método al que le mandas el `SELECT`: **es raro que le mandes la misma variable dos veces, como variable simple y dentro de un array: `executeNonQuery($select,array($select))`** ¿?  ... ¿Si ejecutas la consulta: `SELECT numFile FROM inventory_list ORDER BY numFile desc LIMIT 1` directamente en el DBMS trae datos? Por curiosidad, ¿por qué no seguiste el camino simple que te explique [en este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/230834/error-al-concatenar-datos-en-php#comment428891_230834)?

Comment: El select para traer el ultimo numFile funciona perfectamente en DBMS asi como el update del otro query.

Comment: Edite la pregunta.. ahora veo que no es la manera de guardar el resultado....

Comment: ¿Usas algún framework o el método `executeNonQuery` es un método que has escrito tú?  Todo depende de ese método. El `var_dump` indica que está devolviendo `0`. Si dices que la consulta funciona bien en el DBMS entonces revisa el método. Aquí no podemos ver cómo él trata los datos y devuelve los resultados. A mí me parece muy raro que ese método tenga que recibir dos veces lo mismo: `executeNonQuery($select,array($select))` ¿a qué se debe eso? Un método no debería recibir nunca la misma cosa dos veces.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88751/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-pato).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas se puede resolver mediante una sola consulta del siguiente modo:

```
$sql='
UPDATE inventory_list 
    SET folio = 
        (
            SELECT 
                x.max 
            FROM ( 
                    SELECT 
                        CONCAT("EST-00",MAX(numFile),"-",DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), "%y")) max 
                    FROM inventory_list 
                  ) x 
        ) 
ORDER BY numFile DESC LIMIT 1; 
';
```

No te asustes por el formato, es bueno identar las consultas para poder comprenderlas mejor y analizarlas.

Simplemente, lo que ocurre aquí es lo siguiente:

- `folio` es actualizado tomando el valor en una sub-consulta
- la sub-consulta concatena `EST-00` con el número más grande de `numFile` y con los dos dígitos del año actual
- ordenamos la consulta general en forma DESCendente y lo LIMITamos a 1 para actualizar solamente el último registro.

Aquí la consulta está en una variable `$sql`, la puedes mandar a ejecución desde PHP a la base de datos. Esta consulta no necesita ser preparada, porque no incluye ningún dato que provenga del exterior, está blindada en ese sentido.

Probablemente la mejor manera de hacer esto sería mediante un `TRIGGER`. Si te interesa explorar esa vía de solución puedes investigar sobre el tema, ensayar un código y si tienes problemas los puedes plantear en una nueva pregunta.

Espero te sea de utilidad.